# migrating osgi bundles running in karaf to spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, migration, osgi, apache-karaf

In my company we have use Apache CXF to build REST endpoints and all services are packaged as OGSi bundles which are run in Apache Karaf.

Can anyone share the knowledge on how to start migrating the whole backend to Spring boot ? I am struggling to find any direction or starting point for it. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be able to start the OSGi container inside the SB app

Comment: @injecteer can you please provider any pointers/links you have on how to it?